# How can i create search bar like that of google contact?

Tags: user-interface, frontend, semantic-ui, searchbar

[Google Contact SearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OgGu.png)

Is it possible to create this using semantic-ui?

Comment: Have you try to code something ? Or look the documentation ? ( https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html )

Comment: Great!! Don't know how did i miss that.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the link etc.. Thx :)